# How do push 2 projects in the same solution to my Github repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, github, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studios 2019. I have made a solution called VitekSky. In this solution there is an MVC project called VitekSky. After I was finished with the 1st project I decided to make a 2nd project in the same solution called VitekAPI. I was able to sync my first project to github but am unable to do so with my second project called VitekAPI. The 1st project VitekSky is in asp.net core 2.2 and the 2nd project is in asp.net core 3.0.

My 2 projects in the same solution:
[image: 2 projects in same solution]
Unable to commit in Team explorer
[image: Unable to commit]
My github only contains the first project called VitekSky:
https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

How do I push everything I have locally onto my github repository?

EDIT:
My VitekSky folder
[image: VitekSky folder]

My VitekAPI folder
[image: My VitekAPI folder]

Comment: You probably added the git repository to a project instead of to the solution. The `.git` folder must be in the same folder as the `*.sln` file above all project folders.

Comment: @Oliver Okay thanks. So how do I move the .git folder to the same folder as *.sln?

Comment: Where can I find the .git folder?. We have a VitekSky.sln in our github repository but no .git folder. We don't have any .git folder locally as well.

Comment: The folder is hidden. You must [show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably added the git repository to a project instead of to the solution. The **.git** folder (the local git repository) must be in the same folder as the ***.sln** file above all project folders. The solution folder is the parent folder of the project folders.

I never made it, but I would suggest the following approach to fix the problem:

- Commit all changes.
- Close Visual Studio and any git tools.
- Back up the solution including the local git repo (in case things go wrong).
- Then manually move the `.git` folder, `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` etc. files to the main folder.
- Re-open Visual Studio.
- Commit (this will result in a huge commit).

To see the **.git** folder you must [Show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @OlivierJacotDescombes Thankyou. 1 I am not able to commit in visual studio but I have saved everything. 2 I have closed Visual Studio. 3 In my repos folder there are many different folders. Each containing a project or solution. Amongst all the folders I have copied the VitekSky folder and the VitekAPI folder and made a copy of them on my desk as a backup. I have edited my original post to include screenshots of the two folders. 4 I can now see hidden files. In my VitekSky folder there is a .git folder .gitignore and .gitattributes. Which folder is the main folder that I should move them to?

Comment: "...\EAL\source\repos\". That's one folder upwards.

Comment: If you click on the solution in the solution explorer, you see its `Path` in the properties window.